# How to create confirm message popup when register?

Tags: forms, drupal

I want to show user data when user click to create account in registration page.
I'm a new for drupal 7. anyone can guide ?

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `showing user data` ?!

Comment: yes, to showing user data

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `showing data`? Do you wanna show the registration form itself? or you wanna show a confirmation message after confirmation?

Comment: Thank you Muhammad Reda. I just want they review all data before create an account.

Comment: Hi Muhammad Reda, thank you for your attention. finally i think i can do it with a simple jquery code; <code>$( "#edit-submit" ).click(function() { var firstname = $('#edit-name').val(); var confirm_text = "Please review your information.\n Firstname = " + firstname; var answer = confirm(confirm_text);
        if (answer){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }</code> everything ok now.